# how to prevent "find" from dive deeper than current directory

Tags: find, rm

I have many directory with lots of files inside them.

I've just compressed that directory respectively become `filename.tar.gz`, `someothername.tar.gz`, etc.

After compressing, I use this bash to delete everything except file name contains `.tar.gz`:
`find . ! -name '*.tar.gz*' | xargs rm -r`

But the problem is `find` will dive too deep inside the directory. Because the directory has been deleted but `find` will dive deep in each directory, many messages displayed, such as:

```
rm: cannot remove `./dirname/index.html': No such file or directory
```

So how to prevent `find` from dive deeper than this level (current directory)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ls`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ls) instead of `find` for your problem:

```
ls | grep -v .tar.gz | xargs rm -rf
```

Answer (score 0):

You can tell find the max depth to recurse:

```
find -maxdepth 1 ....
```